# How do I punctuate a quoted question that doesn't end a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

I want my character to ask a question, but I don't know the rules to punctuation. I'll give an example. Is it:

> "Are you ready to go?" He asked his wife.

Or is it:

> "Are you ready to go," He asked his wife.

I'm not sure on this, because I've seen authors do it both ways, and people have said to do it both ways. I just want to do it the most correct way there is.

Answer (score 1):

I would include the question mark within the quotes, as it forms part of the dialog. This is important since the quoted text might not obviously be a question, otherwise.

I would go with the rules here:
http://theeditorsblog.net/2010/12/08/punctuation-in-dialogue/

"Are you ready to go?" he asked his wife.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is correct. It should be "Are you ready to go," he asked his wife. As for research to support this assertion, I'd cite several thousand English novels.